# My friend had left school ___ the age of 14 and gone to work ___ a restro

Tags: prepositions

What prepositions should I use to fill in these two blanks?

> My friend had left school _____ the age of 14 and gone to work _____ a retro.

options:

a) under/in
b) at/in
c) under/around
d) on/in
e) about/in

My approach:

I am confused between a) and b)

I think both can be true.

Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: Unless really informal context, "and *gone* to work" should be "and *went* to work".

Comment: I don't know what "a restro" or "a retro" is in this context; those aren't standard English.  Is it supposed to be short for *a restaurant*?

Comment: @stangdon I've never heard it either, but googling "restro" produces a page of results for establishments in India so I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that it's in fairly common use there? Can any of our Indian contributors confirm?

Answer (score 1):

I think b) is correct here.

"My friend had left school under the age of 14" sounds strange.

"**Before** the age of 14" would work better.

Comment: I agree. Since "left school" is a specific action in the past that you are aware of, it is unlikely you would not want to be specific about the age.

Answer (score 0):

**B)** is the obvious winner as far as I can tell. Age can take only one preposition—[at](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/at).

With that said, the natural choice should be **B)**.

> My friend had left school **at** the age of 14 and gone to work **in** a restro (restaurant).

Comment: There are similar contexts where age can take a different preposition.  For example, "Mr. Scrooge was accused of violating child labor laws.  He allegedly hired children under the age of 14 to work as forklift operators."